# Why doesn't my consumer console sync up with my text file?

Tags: apache-kafka

I set up everything as recommended for a quick start, **I used a text file as a source or producer which contains one sentence. when I launch a consumer console for the first time I am able to read the sentence (JSON format) in the file but when I add something in the file it's not showing in the consumer console** and when I use the producer console to add something in the topic, it shows right the way in the consumer console. What could be the problem?

zookeeper UP

Connector UP

consumer UP

producer UP

Kafka    UP

Comment: Can you link to the particular quickstart that you're using? And what version of the software? And what is your host operating system?

Comment: https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/apache-kafka-connector/ 
I am using  kafka-2.4.1  and ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't watch files for changes. You would need to program your own code to detect file modifications on disk then restart the producer thread to pick up those changes

Alternatively, use kafka-connect-spooldir connector, available on Github

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007 I will try that solution

Answer (score 0):

I created a new topic and placed the file to the wrong path, so I had to edit these files:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh 
config/connect-standalone.properties 
config/connect-file-source.properties 
config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

---------- edit these lines------------------------------

```
topic=my_created_topic
file=PATH_TO_MY_SOURCE_FILE
```

Everything is working perfectly, yah!!!!!!!!!!